# How to copy multi-line text from Excel without quotes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, copy-paste

When you create a multi-line string in an excel cell (by using Alt-Enter), if you copy that cell to a text editor, excel will automatically add double quotes (") around the full string, ie:

```
Cell1  |   Simple String 1 
Cell2  |   First line of a 
       |   Multiline string
       |   with 3 lines 
Cell3  |   Another simple line 2
```

When you copy just the column with values to a text editor, we get:

```
Simple String 1
"First line of a 
Multiline string
with 3 lines"
Another simple line 2
```

How can I tell excel not to add the quote around multi-line text when copying from excel?

---

Edit:  Text Editors that I've tried that display this behaviour:

- MS Word
- Wordpad
- Notepad
- Notepad++
- SQL Server Studio

If you have a suggestion on using a particular editor (or one of the above) please tell me which one & how to use it...

Comment: For what it's worth, it's because Excel [tries to output valid CSV](http://superuser.com/questions/302334/true-difference-between-excelcsv-and-standard-csv/302338#302338). I'd be surprised if this was easy to change.

Comment: @slhck I *hope* you're wrong (nice answer on that though!), as it would be very useful to be able to tell excel that I'm not copying to csv...

Comment: This is very annoying.  There is no legitimate reason why Excel is putting quotes around text that contains a carriage return.

Comment: Google Spreadsheets does the same annoying thing. I'm trying to copy several cells of data into a text file, but Google Spreadsheets adds quotes to the data - the quotes are NOT in the source data. This is a bug to me, not a feature.

Comment: There is an answer that uses VBA posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24913557/976210 This worked much better for me as I don't want to have to use an intermediary program.

Comment: It's not just carriage returns. The same thing happens with tab characters `CHAR(9)`.

Comment: Here is a work around https://stackoverflow.com/a/60251126/1279373

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How your text gets copied in to Word depends on the formatting option chosen. In Word 2010, the default format option is `HTML Format`. There are four main options for how to copy text into Word. (`Formatted Text (RTF)`, `Unformatted Text`, `HTML Format`, & `Unformatted Unicode Text`)

Pasting in with formatted text creates mini tables in Word. (The blue outlines.)

[image: Paste Special Options]

To get unformatted text in Word without the double quotes:

1. Paste the text in formatted so it creates the table.
2. Select the table and copy it.
3. Move to a blank spot and paste the new copy as unformatted text. (`Alt + E`, `S`)

This also works to paste the results without quotes into another editor. Simply alter step 3 to paste into the other editor.

It would probably be faster however, to simply paste as normal and then use Replace to find and remove all double quotes.

Comment: +1 nice answer with technique to solve it!  (unfortunately for the block I was dealing with, there were valid double quotes that I wanted to keep)

Comment: +1 these stupid things really make me wanna look for a different office product. Maybe star office or something. thanks for the trick

Comment: Just use CLEAN function. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910288/leave-out-quotes-when-copying-from-cell

Answer (score 39):

If you copy a range from Excel (2010) to Word, you will get the text as you want it, quotes free. Then you may copy it again to its final destination, eg notepad. Excel->Word->Notepad will give you the results that you want.

Comment: Word does display this behaviour, when you copy with other cells (as described in the question). Or is this something they've sorted in Office 2010?

Comment: So far, this works.  It's too bad I have to use Word 2010 as a middle man to remove the quotes, though.

Comment: This works for Mac Office 2011 too.

Comment: Works in current Mac Office 365.

Comment: Using Excel>Word>Notepad
I find that the newlines that I have added into Excel cells have disappeared when I pasted from Word back to Notepad, so I paste to Notepad, then back to Word, then replace the last character on each line (which is fortunately the same uniqute character in my text) with the same character ^13^10 then paste back to Notepad!

If I don't use the Word route then not only are quotes added at the end of lines but all double quotes are doubled up (escaped) as well.

Answer (score 8):

1. I typed `=A2`, which references the cell with the `CHAR` in the formula.
2. I then copied `A2` and pasted as values into another cell, for example `A3`.
3. I then selected `A3`, pressed <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.
4. Stop right there don't paste into another Excel cell. Leave it in clipboard and paste into Notepad.
5. The invisible quotes disappear.

Disappear like INXS said, Disappear! :=)

Comment: Gosh is this the best way? :(

Answer (score 6):

I used the `CLEAN` function and it worked for me.

Put the cells you want to copy inside `CLEAN`, for example:

```
=clean(A1)
```

Where `A1` is the cell with the data you want to copy to notepad without the quotes.

Comment: I think you mean `CLEAN`. (At least in Excel 2010.) However that would remove the line feed characters and his second sentence would no longer be multiline.

Comment: This should be the answer or at least deserves more upvotes. No extra tools required. Simple change (wrapping) of the formula.

Comment: CLEAN() removes the LineFeed character though, so it won't work

Answer (score 6):

You can get around this by highlighting the cell and then copy and pasting the code directly out of the text bar at the top by clicking in to it and highlighting it all manually.

I've only done this in Excel 2010 so I don't know if this will work for earlier versions.

Comment: This is perfect although I had to take my cell that had the CONCAT(A1:A100) formula in it and Paste Special into a second cell before I could select everything from the text box like you described

Comment: This is the answer which should be getting the love! Simple, effective, requires no other steps than to copy from the formula bar instead of the cell itself. Thanks @Matt!

Comment: Doesn't work for Excel 365 for Mac - the quotes are still there when I paste

Comment: This does not work with formulas (you can get around this by pressing F9, but you need to take care not to save it ..  so acceptable workaround, but not an ideal solution).
Btw nice shortcut to avoid fiddling with mouse is to use F2.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way that I've found is to concatenate the cells that you want to be on multiple lines with something "special" between them, rather than cr/lf. Tilde usually works well for me. For example, in column G:

```
=E1&"~"&F1
=E2&"~"&F2
...
```

In this example, the end goal is to get a text file with the values from E1 on one line, followed by F1 on a new line, followed by E2, F2, etc. Of course you could have just as easily built G1 from other values, just included ~ for the the line breaks.

Then to get multi-line text file in Notepad++

- Cut and paste into Notepad++
- Ctrl-H to open replace dialog
- Make sure the "extended" search option is selected
- Replace all ~ with \n  (or \r\n if you prefer)

Comment: As a developer i like this one since it does not requires 3rd tool like Word.

Answer (score 3):

Install the generic/text only printer in Windows, selecting `Print to file` as a port.

Print your selected range to this printer - the text file it creates will be free of quotes.

Comment: You might be older than I am ha ha

Answer (score 2):

It's not Excel's problem.  Like the previous poster says, it's just outputting valid CSV data.  It's going to be up to the editor you're putting it into to look after formatting it.  I would suggest using something a little smarter than notepad... You could use MS Word as a go-between from Excel to whatever text editor you wanted to use besides word.

Comment: I do use something other than notepad...  Also Word does exactly the same thing (pasting just that cell in with "'s)

Comment: Word 2010 with default settings works perfectly well as a go-between.

Comment: I discovered this yesterday. I agree with Andrew Bickerton. I don´t want to copy CSV, I want to copy text. Excel should at least ask. Since my text was about two thousand SQL inserts, I was able to solve it moreless easily with PsPad. Despite of being easy, it was completely unnecesary.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the Excel document as a web-page, and then copy the text from the webpage. This works well for a single column of data, but make sure you set the width of the column to the width of the text, otherwise it will add line-breaks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and used the following steps (I'm using Office 2007, but I think it works for later versions, as well):

1. Selected the range of cells containing multi-line text from Excel that I want to paste into another editor, and then choose Copy.
2. In Word 2007, I pasted the copied range of cells as a table.
3. Select the table.
4. On the Layout tab, choose Select-Table.
5. In the data section, choose Convert to Text and choose Paragraph marks.

The result is the original table converted to text, with newline characters at the end of each line and paragraph marks at the end of the last line from each cell.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be to prep it for a CSV file because they'd be pretty stupid be so sophisticated as to top and tail cells that contain non-printing characters with quotes and not do the same for cells that contain commas (which it doesn't).

Anyway. I came across this problem when I tried to create address labels from First Name, Surname, Address Line 1 ... fields as:

```
=A1&" "&B1&CHAR(13)&CHAR(10)&C1&CHAR(13)&CHAR(10)&D1
```

`CHAR(13)` followed by `CHAR(10)` being a new paragraph when viewing a text file with a hex editor.

My way round this annoyance is to:

- copy and paste the cells/column into Word.
- Use the clipboard symbol dropdown (bottom left of page or pasted text) to select, *Keep text only*.
- Select the pasted text. You only have to do this if the document contains other stuff that might be affected
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the *Find and Replace* dialogue box.
- In the, *Find what*, field type in: `"^p"` (all four characters).
  You might have to go to Tools -> AutoCorrect options then both AutoFormat tabs to make sure it doesn't change your straight quotes)
- In the, *Replace with*, field, enter: `^p` (2 chars)
- Now hit the, *Replace All*, button
- Finally you will have to manually
  delete the double-quotes at the beginning and end of the imported
  block

This is based on Office 2003 so your version of Microsoft Word might be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

> I had the same issue and I did that:

1. Click `New Email` in Outlook.
2. Paste ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> ) what you've been copied from Excel into it.
3. Select all ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ) and recopy all ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> ).
4. Paste it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but my solution was to use CLEAN as suggested, copy those cells and paste the values back into a sheet.  That way, I could edit the text to the final result and copy and paste the cells into a text document without the quotes.

I think that cleaning the text first then doing the final formatting would most likely work (at least, it did for me).

Comment: One thing to note, I believe the "Clean" method will remove the carriage return characters as well and the resulting past will not be multi line.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, finally fixed it very easily.  I had 600 rows of long product descriptions.  To fix this issue, I did the following:

1) Select the entire column and click 'Wrap Text.'

2) Keeping the column selected, click 'Wrap Text' AGAIN (so that the text is 100% NOT wrapped).

PRESTO - the text copied out of each cell perfectly, without quotes (even though they were long paragraphs).

By default, Excel adds quotes to any multi-line text.  So the simple solution, provided by the above process, is to ensure that your cells with long text are not automatically wrapping onto multiple lines.

It might be worthwhile to note that before I did this, the cells looked normal and did NOT appear to be wrapped.  I think the process above 'tells' Excel to NOT interpret any cell as being 'multi-line' text, even if it is a long paragraph, thus solving the 'Excel adding quotes to copied text' issue.

Comment: Hi, not quite the right solution. That only works if you don't have any internal carriage returns in your cells (press alt-enter to create an internal carriage return)

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy work around for this. Install OpenOffice Calc and open the .xlsx file. Then simply copy the cell contents and paste into any text editor. The annoying leading and trailing quotes will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem and none of the solutions of this post helped me.
Then I'll share the solution which definitely worked well for me, in case others may be in the same situation.

First, this solution also complies with one bug recently reported to Microsoft, which was causing the clipboard content to be transformed into unreadable content, after any modification using VBA when the user accessed any "Quick Acces Folder" using file explorer.

> Documentation for the solution of the copy past bug, which the code will be used in this answer, to remove the quotes from clipboard: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/send-information-to-the-clipboard

You'll need to build a macro as below, and assign the "ctrl+c" as a hotkey to it. (Hotkey assignment = Developer tab, Macros, click the macro, options, then put the letter "c" in the hotkey field).

```
Sub ClipboardRemoveQuotes()
    Dim strClip As String
    strClip = Selection.Copy
    strClip = GetClipboard()
    On Error Resume Next - Needed in case clipboard is empty
    strClip = Replace(strClip, Chr(34), "") 
    On Error GoTo 0
    SetClipboard (strClip)
End Sub
```

This will still need for you to build the functions "SetClipboard" and "GetClipboard".

Below we have the definition of the "SetClipboard" and "GetClipboard" functions, with a few adjustments to fit different excel versions. (Put the below code in a module)

```
    Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EmptyClipboard Lib "User32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "User32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetClipboardData Lib "User32" (ByVal wFormat As LongPtr, ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
    Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As Long, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Sub SetClipboard(sUniText As String)
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim iStrPtr As LongPtr
        Dim iLock As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim iStrPtr As Long
        Dim iLock As Long
    #End If
    Dim iLen As Long
    Const GMEM_MOVEABLE As Long = &H2
    Const GMEM_ZEROINIT As Long = &H40
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = &HD
    OpenClipboard 0&
    EmptyClipboard
    iLen = LenB(sUniText) + 2&
    iStrPtr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT, iLen)
    iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
    lstrcpy iLock, StrPtr(sUniText)
    GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
    SetClipboardData CF_UNICODETEXT, iStrPtr
    CloseClipboard
End Sub

Public Function GetClipboard() As String
#If VBA7 Then
    Dim iStrPtr As LongPtr
    Dim iLock As LongPtr
#Else
    Dim iStrPtr As Long
    Dim iLock As Long
#End If
    Dim iLen As Long
    Dim sUniText As String
    Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = 13&
    OpenClipboard 0&
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) Then
        iStrPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
        If iStrPtr Then
            iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
            iLen = GlobalSize(iStrPtr)
            sUniText = String$(iLen \ 2& - 1&, vbNullChar)
            lstrcpy StrPtr(sUniText), iLock
            GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
        End If
        GetClipboard = sUniText
    End If
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

I hope it may help others as well as it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The other day, I stumbled upon the same old issue almost a decade after this topic was started. The proposed solutions here required additional steps, adding complexity that I wanted to avoid. So I found an alternative way that worked for me.

I needed to process some data in Excel and output a few numeric values integrated into XML code.

### My Core Idea

Processed data (simplifed)

```
Item 1
Item 2
```

Desired output (simplified)

```
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
```

Initially, I tried to generate the output as multiline text in a single cell using CHAR(10). The text copied to my XML file looked like this

```
"<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>"
```

Then I came to understand that I simply need to create each line of code in a separate cell and copy the lines.

[each line of code in a separate cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg8Le.png)

That solved the issue for me.

And when you think of it, why create a multiline text in a single cell if you intend to insert it in some other software? If, for any reason, you also need to have it in a single cell in Excel, you can just create the text in multiple cells in another worksheet and concatenate it in your worksheet using CHAR(10) or CHAR(13).

### My Actual Issue

I used Excel to calculate coordinates for some XML structures, then I needed to integrate the coordinates into the pre-defined lines of XML code.

```
svg:x="[coor_x]cm"
svg:y="[coor_y]cm"
```

Since I had many pairs of coordinates, it seemed natural to generate multiline text for each pair of coordinates so that I can drag the formula down easily.

[each cell contains two lines for coor_x and coor_y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOnkT.png)

But the output inserted in a different software was less than desirable:

```
"svg:x=""1.43cm""
svg:y=""2.47cm"""
"svg:x=""0.53cm""
svg:y=""2.12cm"""
```

Another approach was to have a formula for *coor_x* in even rows and a different formula for *coor_y* in odd rows. But then I would lose the ability to drag formulas down as many rows as I need. I would need to copy and paste this pair of formulas below a lot of times and re-adjust wrong references to cells storing coordinates.

[pair of formulas in two rows that need to be copied multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr18C.png)

Finally, once I found that my version of Excel supported dynamic arrays, it dawned on me how to do it properly. (I believe it should also work on older versions of Excel using named ranges.)

I generated all lines for *coor_x* in one column, then generated all lines for *coor_y* in another column, then used a modified version of the [formula](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/unique-values-for-an-array-of-n-rows-and-m-columns.1149686/page-2#posts) to stack data from the two columns into a single column:

```
=LET(a,TRANSPOSE(A8:B9),r,ROWS(a),seq,SEQUENCE(r*COLUMNS(a),,0),arr,INDEX(a,MOD(seq,r)+1,seq/r+1),arr)
```

[generate all lines for coor_x in one column, generate all lines for coor_y in another column, use the formula below to stack data from multiple columns into a single column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdK5.png)

Using dynamic arrays in creative ways, you can even do away with the need to adjust array regions manually when you add more pairs of coordinates.

Hope this solution will also be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach that can work with any software...

My use case includes quoted strings build in Excel (things like `msgid "ThisLabel"`) that get doubled with the copy (`msgid ""ThisLabel""`).

I use [Free Clipboard Viewer](https://freeclipboardviewer.com/), which allows you to view all the different format of the copied data.  With my text copied from Excel, I switch to Rich Text Format (RTF) and copy THAT.  Everything is cleaned up and I can simply paste it anywhere I need it.

[image: RTF version]>
[image: Copy from Excel]

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with copying result from C1 procesed by formula.
My intent was to prepare JSON.

Example of concatenate strings:

```
  A         B          C
1 string1   tabOnEnd   string1tabOnEnd
```

Old result of copy:
"string1tabOnEnd    "

The problem was in new line symbol and tab symbol. So I replace all new lines by \n and all tabs with \t

New result of copy:
string1tabOnEnd\t

Replace formula:
`= SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2; "\"; "\\"); """"; "\"""); CHAR(10); "\n"); "   "; "\t")`

Maybe you can use similar formula to remove tab symbol and new line symbol. It should prevent adding quotes.
`= SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2; CHAR(10); ""); " "; "")`

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: How to prevent copy text from cell with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Initially, I copied a range of cells and pasted them into a Word document. Afterward, I copied and pasted from there into my Notepad++.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Like you I had my data in a column. So to copy the values without those quotes, I concatenate the whole column with the data. This is for Google Docs spreadsheets but I guess it could work for Excel, might have to change the CONCATENATE function.

To concatenate the whole G column:

```
=CONCATENATE(G:G)
```

It added quotes only first and last and that's easy enough to edit by hand later.

Comment: doesn't work for excel

Answer (score -1):

working on the answer from solvus, we can create an autopublish webpage, with just the range of text you want - without quotes. you can then copy and paste this to other locations. Once you set it up, its there forever and uptodate without messing with your main file.

to do this,...

Select your cells and then `save as`..
`save as file type` = `Single File Web Page`.
with the option `Republish $ : $`(your selected range.)

click publish.
select `AutoRepublish every time this workbook is saved`.

- you will then get a Webpage published which has just your ranged data, in a table format with no quotes. copy and paste :)