# Stop Excel from putting double quotes around copied cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

In cell A1 I have the value:

```
test
```

in cell C1 I have the formula:

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & "attempt"
```

when I copy the value of C1 to Notepad++.exe it adds double quotes around the value.ie:

```
"test
attempt"
```

What will allow me to copy the formula (with my line break) so that no double quotes are added?

expected result:

```
 test
 attempt
```

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/324271/how-to-copy-multi-line-text-from-excel-without-quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is default Excel behaviour.