# Paste from text editor to spreadsheet keeping CR in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, carriage-return

I have tried this in Notepad and Notepad++, but can't get it to work. What I want to do is close to the opposite of this post: [How to copy multi-line text from Excel without quotes?](https://superuser.com/questions/324271/how-to-copy-multi-line-text-from-excel-without-quotes)   I want to paste into a spreadsheet and keep the text in a single cell. The headache is the CRLF; there seems to be no find/replace options to create the Excel equivalent of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The original text is coming from emails and so probably carries HTML formatting, but I would be happy to use a text editor as an intermediate step for the reformat find/replace. Did anyone deal with this problem before?

Comment: Don't paste directly into the cell.  Click the cell you want to paste into, then paste into the entry bar at the top of the sheet.  The CRs will be retained.

Answer (score 2):

Paste the text into the formula bar, instead of into the cell.

Comment: Thanks Paul, never would have found that trick. Further, after you have done it once (and first for that column) it seems that in excel2010 it remembers and next time you can just paste straight into the cell (no need to select cell and then paste into formula bar). Great trick.

Comment: umm, it seems it might be a bit random for it to keep working after you have done it once. Also note this paste into the formula bar works in the google spreadsheet.