# Remove double-quotation when copying from cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

**Problem**:
While copying a cell which contains 'script' from Excel into another program, double-quotation marks (`""`) are added automatically instead of single-quotation mark only (`"`).

Also, at the beginning and end of scripts, a `"` is automatically added.

Here is my script, and the emphasized quotes are the extraneous ones:

> ***"***// script to change budget by day of week
>   // Jon Gritton 2016
>
> // user vars
>   var BUDG_NAME = ***"***  "Shared budget S104 (CX - High)"  ***"***;
>   var B_MON = 
>   500000
>   ;
>   var B_TUE = 
>   500000
>   ;
>   var B_WED = 
>   500000
>   ;
>   var B_THU = 
>   500000
>   ;
>   var B_FRI = 
>   500000
>   ;
>   var B_SAT = 
>   500000
>   ;
>   var B_SUN = 
>   500000
>   ;
>
> function main() {
>   setBudget(getBudgetToday());
>   }
>
> function getBudgetToday() {
>   var budgArray = [B_SUN,B_MON,B_TUE,B_WED,B_THU,B_FRI,B_SAT];
>   var d = new Date(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), >AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone(), ***"***  "MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss" 
>    ***"***));
>   var today = d.getDay();
>   return budgArray[today];
>   }
>
> function setBudget(budgetToday) {
>   Logger.log(***"***  "Budget for today is: "  ***"*** + budgetToday);
>   var budgetIter = AdWordsApp.budgets()
>   .withCondition(***"***  "BudgetName = '"  ***"*** + BUDG_NAME + ***"***  "  '   " 
>    ***"***)
>   .get()
>   while (budgetIter.hasNext()) {
>   var thisBudget = budgetIter.next();
>   thisBudget.setAmount(budgetToday);
>   }
>   }***"***

**Details**:
I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows 10.

I've read on other thread that we can solve this by using this macro

```
Sub CopyCellContents()
  'create a reference in the VBE to Microsft Forms 2.0 Lib
  Dim objData As New DataObject
  Dim strTemp As String
  strTemp = ActiveCell.Value
  objData.SetText (strTemp)
  objData.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

but apparently this macro is only compatible with Excel 2007, and not Excel 2013:

**"Compile error: User-defined type not defined"**

The only work-around is to copy the cell (that contains the script) into Word 2013 and copy the text through blocking the formula bar. But I need to just copy the cell to the new program.

How can I keep these double-quotes from showing up when copying to another program? In other words, can I get rid of these double quotation marks from being automatically added when the cell is copied to clipboard?

Comment: Multiline text copied from Excel automatically includes quotation marks. See this similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/324271/how-to-copy-multi-line-text-from-excel-without-quotes

Comment: @davidmneedham That's probably where freakyholic got the macro from. [This comment](//superuser.com/q/324271/#comment1269458_324271) on the question leads to [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/24913557/976210) to another question where the very same macro resides.

Comment: @robinCTS , you're probably right. Is this a duplicate question?

Comment: @davidmneedham Given that the problem is not so much that the quotes need removing, but that the solutions found in that other question aren't working (which my answer solves), I would say no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that macro *is* compatible with Excel 2013. What you need to do is add a reference to the `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library`, as explained in the comment on the second line of the code.

In the VBE, go to `Tools` → `References…`, scroll down until you find the Forms reference (it will be under "M") and tick the checkbox:

[image: Add References Screenshot]

The macro should work now.