# How to copy multi-line text from LibreOffice Calc WITH quotes

Tags: windows-10, csv, libreoffice-calc

I've been searching and found this question...  [How to copy multi-line text from Excel without quotes?](https://superuser.com/questions/324271/how-to-copy-multi-line-text-from-excel-without-quotes/324491?newreg=7230262845d34bf387ab8526fd7903e4) ...which is almost exactly the opposite problem I have.

I am using LibreOffice Calc and I have created a small spreadsheet in which some cell have multi line text.

I would like to copy the whole spreadsheet and paste it into a website. The website requires that multi-line cells have quoted text but I can't get it to quote the text when I copy/paste.

I have tried saving the document as a CSV file and that does quote the text but I am using Japanese kana in the document and can't get the encoding to work.

**Edit**

OK, after further searching I have found this thread... https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113571

It appears to show a fix for this problem (sort of). The fix applied seems to accommodate both quoted and unquoted multi line cells.

It has an... option? setting? ... `SotClipboardFormatId::STRING_TSVC` that will allow it to quote multi line text cells.

I just don't know where to set this to turn it on.

I'm running LibreOffice 6.1.2.1 and this fix was pushed to master for 6.0 so it looks like I should be able to access it.

**Side note**

In the end I gave up and installed Microsoft Office and Excel. That worked fine. Would still be interested to find out how I can do this with LibreOffice though.