# Saving to CSV file always adds quotation marks in OpenOffice

Tags: csv, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to use OpenOffice Calc for editing CSV files with `TAB` as delimiter. No matter what I do, Calc is insisting on adding quotation marks (") to the strings. If a cell content is number only, it's fine.

Is there a way to not let Calc do this? I mean, the TAB is enough for any parser, right?

Comment: To save without quotes check this [post][1]  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10913144

Answer (score 1):

#### Why do you need double quotes?

> I mean, the TAB is enough for any parser, right?

No, it technically isn't! As mentioned in my answer about [Excel's CSV format](https://superuser.com/q/302334/48078), the [Common Format and MIME Type for CSV Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) (RFC 4180) specifies that:

> … each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
> some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
> at all). If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
> double quotes may not appear inside the fields.

So far, so good. Calc obviously chooses to always enclose it in double quotes.

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas should be enclosed in double-quotes

… so this is where a double quote **has to be** in order for the CSV to be parsed correctly again.

#### Why does Calc add them?

Calc is probably doing that as a safety measure for all text fields. On the contrary, what Excel is doing is somewhat ambiguous.

#### How can you avoid them?

I found [a forum post](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=280307&sid=becdb19214c1a8a30479cb44b960df5a#280307) that suggests using a macro to disable text delimiters:

```
Dim oDocCsv As Object       
Dim CsvProperties(2) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue 

.... 

CsvProperties(0).Name    = "FilterName" 
CsvProperties(0).Value   = "Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)" 
CsvProperties(1).Name    = "FilterOptions" 
CsvProperties(1).Value   = "124,0,ANSI,2" 

.... 

oDocCsv.storeAsURL("test.csv", CsvProperties())
```

The important option here is the line with `124,0,ANSI,2`. According to the [Filter Options reference](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options), the second part (i.e. the `0`) disables text delimiters upon export.

Comment: I don't have OpenOffice to try this, nor have I ever used it, but let me know if that works for you. It might be that the macro has to be used a bit differently, but the important part is the filter option value.

Answer (score 0):

Open TSV file(with double quotes) in notepad++

1. Replace `""` by `"`
2. Replace `\t"` by `\t`
3. Replace `"\t` by `\t`

[notepad++ replace dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofPBd.png)

and you are done....